# Python Regular expression for password matching(re)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to validate the entered password based on  the following conditions

1.Should contain at least 2 uppercase letters

2.Should contain at least 2 lowercase letters

3.Minimum length of the strings must be 6

4.Should contain at least 2 digits

5.Should contain at least 1 special character

6.Total password length must be 10

I tried to create a pattern something like

```
import re
res=re.match(r'[[A-Z{2,}][a-z{2,}][0-9{2,}][/s]+]{10}',"AaBb69%#Ag")
print res
```

But it returned None.Anyone please help me.!!!!!

Comment: Instead of trying your regexp as a whole, and then not knowing how to debug it, here’s one way you might approach the problem: try starting with the first component `[A-Z{2,}]` and see if that matchhes, then add the next and see if that matches, etc. Once you find something that doesn’t match, it shold then be easier for you to figure out why it doesn’t work. Also test your partial pattern with other “valid” passwords - in fact build yourself a list of good passwords that must be accepted AND of bad passwords that mustn’t. Good luck.

Comment: BTW building the lists of good and bad passwords may expose incompatibility in your “conditions”. And bear in mind tht your problem may not be solvable in a single regular expression.

Comment: It's returning None because the regex expression excludes characters % and #. Add 'special characters' to your regex.

Comment: @barny :I 've splitted the components and tested it.It works fine with conditions.Is it not possible to join them???

Comment: @GeneByun:i omitted the 5th condition.But it shows None.Thanks

Comment: Now combine them, adding one at a time and retesting against good and bad passwords. And as a bad password try matching against “aA”, “AAa”,”aAA” etc. There’s no magic here, it’s all quite logical, although complex.

Comment: *3.Minimum length of the strings must be 6* and *6.Total password length must be 10* make this question too uinclear.

Comment: Okay, I think the square brackets inside the square brackets are what's causing problems. It will look for `[` in your password, so leave the outermost square brackets and delete all the rest.

Comment: @GeneByun:I used the outer square bracket for checking the minimum length condition [  ]{10}

Comment: No the square brackets don’t work like that. They contain character sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done with a single regular expression. You need to match a different regular expression for each constraint, and the password is only valid if every one matches.

For your constraint of at least two uppercase characters, match two uppercase characters with anything in between: `r'[A-Z].*[A-Z]'`

For lowercase: `r'[a-z].*[a-z]'`

For digits: `r'[0-9].*[0-9]'`

For at least one special character: `r'[!@#$%^&*()-_=+]'`, where the brackets contain what special characters you allow.

For length, minimum of 6, maximum of 10: `r'^.{6,10}$'`

While you can do this with regular expressions, you may find it easier to simply write the constraints without them in ordinary python. Taking length as an example, you could just do

`if 6 <= len(password) and len(password) <= 10:`

instead of using regular expressions.